# SnowFlake Stored Procedure with input variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

New to Snowflake, I am looking for sample code which will read data files from aws s3 bucket, and insert records to Snowflake table. This stored procedure will take 3 input variables are **year, month and day**.
Snowflake objects are created (Integration with name dev_integ_s3_connection, and Stage name dev_stage_connection). How can I parameterized stored procedure to take input values?

```
COPY INTO  "DB_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME".PROCESSED_TABLE
FROM (select $1  from @dev_stage_connection/process_table/year=$year/month=$month/day=$day)
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = FILE_FORMAT.READ_S3_ORC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass parameters into your SP and then reference them in your code e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_name(P1 VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
return P1;
$$
;
```